# How do i get latest comments without using FQL with the help of graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am looking to get the latest comments for the Facebook page which I have created, I can fetch it using FQL, but now I don't want to use FQL Because it'll be Deprecated after few months, so I need to Do it through Open Graph API,

Can anybody help me out here?

Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/feed

> /{page-id}/tagged shows the posts that this page was tagged in and the 'posts to page'

...if you mean the user posts. If you want to get the latest comments to page posts, you need to get the latest posts with `/page-id/feed` first and use the `/post-id/comments` endpoint for each one. Or easier: `/page-id/feed?fields=comments`

If you need older entries, you need to use paging: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#paging

Comment: First of all thank you @luschan, i have an idea about what you explained here, but that is not what i want, i just want only comments, what issue occurs when i go through this (/page-id/feed), it gives me new post and comments, but if i want comments for old posts then?
FQL is providing facility to get Latest comments only, and i would not like to go for this (/post-id/comments) because i have many post to fetch comments, so this may not be feasible.. Please me some other suggestion.

Comment: there is no other option, if you need older entries too you need to implement paging. i will add a link for that.